# Autodetection of OS in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, cross-platform

Is there any way to autodetect your Operating System using your C/C++ code? I need this for running some crossplatform code for Linux, Windows, even on a Raspberry Pi. I am trying to autodetect the OS so that I am not put in the situation that I have to ask for the OS that is  running on the machine as an input.

I was thinking about a hack like verifying the file system structure or something like that, I don't know if I am on to something or not.

Comment: The answer to this really depends on what you want to achieve with the difference. Typically, the correct thing is to use pre-defined macros like Jeegar Patel says, but it is often also useful to detect this in the build system, and pick the right compiler, etc.

Comment: On POSIX systems, if you are building natively (no cross-compilation), you could use `uname` in the build commands

Comment: You want a binary that can magically be executed on several different operating system and then detect at run-time which it is running on? No way. I feel that C++ may be the wrong solution to your problem, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used below code in past for checking between linux and windows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

#ifdef _WIN32
   printf("in Windows");
#endif

#ifdef linux
    printf("In Linux");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Usually all toolchain has their own  predefined macros so you need to use those macros to detect which os is this.

List of such predefined macros.

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

---

Yes as a side note, Here detection of OS is happened using compile time macros. So according to toolchain respective macro's defination will go in build.

To detect OS version in **runtime**, like in java we do

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Same way in C/C++ we do not have any API.

---

In POSIX systems using '[uname](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/uname/)' we can get OS name.

Comment: This is not auto-detect as OP asked for, this is conditional build.

Comment: @GeorgeAndré Where is the difference?

Comment: @FUZxxl Here we are detecting os at compile time, Not run time.

Comment: @JeegarPatel In what way is that not what OP wants?

Comment: @FUZxxl Updated my answer. So in code, we do not do something like Os=checkOs(); if(Os==windows) {Its windows} else if(Os==linux) {Its linux }\

Comment: @Jeeger POSIX provides `uname()` for this purpose, but that's not available on Windows as far as I know.

Comment: However, POSIX systems have the [uname](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/uname/) function to query the OS

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes  its right, but from programing language point of view, we do not have such APIs in c and c++

Answer (score 5):

There is this handy list ( save it to disk ! ).  List of [predefined compiler macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

I would also suggest that if you are targeting multiple platforms, look for a library that's already available for them.

Comment: BTW, both [Qt](http://qt.io/) and [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) are cross-platform C++ libraries worth looking into.